# Ajax Servlet Issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

The problem here is, if i make a search, the results are returned then shortly after the process is done, the page changes to the servlet with json raw data.
I am confused here.

**This JSP submits the form**

```
<form class="col-lg-12" action="./urllinks" method="GET" id="searchform">

                        <div class="input-group"
                            style="width: 340px; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">
                            <input class="form-control input-lg" title="Make a wish !."
                                placeholder="Go on and search ! Don't be shy :p" type="text" id="box"
                                name="query"> <span class="input-group-btn"><button
                                    class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="searchresult" type="submit">Search</button></span>
                        </div>

</form>
```

**This is the Servlet doGET**

```
    String word = request.getParameter("query");
    List<Page> results = DynamoDbMethods.search(word);

    String reply = new Gson().toJson(results); 

    response.setContentType("text/json"); 
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    response.getWriter().write(reply);
```

**This is the Javascript AJAX**

```
$('#searchform').submit(function(){
            var query = $("#box").val();

        //  alert(query);
            $.ajax({
              target:"#map", 
                dataType: "json",
                type: 'GET',
                data:{query: query},
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/path/urllinks',
                success: function(response) {
                    successCallback(response);}

          });
        });

function successCallback(responseObj){
  #This function just prints the data on a table
  #e.g 
 $.each(responseObj, function(index, element){ alert(element.title);}

}
```

I tried to eliminate : `action="./urllinks" method="GET"` but then no data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have not prevented the default non-ajax form submit from triggering.

Your function can take an event param and you can use this to prevent the default.

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {   
        $('#searchform').submit(   
            function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                //rest of code
            }
        );
    }
);
```

There is actually a Jquery plugin at the below where you can reduce all the boilerplate to a couple of lines of js.

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/