# New JSP page is opened instead of loading JSP into DIV of current page

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, jsp

I want to load some data into div `users` after clicking on `Submit`. I use ajax for this purpose. The problem is that the page `http://localhost:8080/myprj/showUsers` is opened on button click event instead of loading this content into div.

**Context.jsp**

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadAjax() {       
    $.ajax({
        url: "context.do", 
        success: function(result) { 
            $("#users").html(result); 
        },
        error : function(e) {
            alert('Error: ' + e);
        }
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Context information</h2>
<form:form method="POST" action="/myprj/showUsers">
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="weather">Weather</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="weather" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="companions">Companions</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="companions" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>  
        <table border="1" cellspacing="1" align="center" style="margin-top: 160px;">
            <tr>
                 <th>Weather</th>
                 <th>Companions</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <td>${weather}</td>
                 <td>${companions}</td>
            </tr>
         </table>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="loadData()" />

</form:form>

<div id = "users"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class Test1 {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/context", method = RequestMethod.GET)   
    public ModelAndView context() {
        return new ModelAndView("context", "command", new Context());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/showUsers", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String showUsers(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")Context context, ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("weather", context.getWeather());
      model.addAttribute("companions", context.getCompanions());
      return "result";
    }

}
```

Comment: You are not overriding the button's default action. Neither are you actually submitting the form. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30467717/ajax-servlet-issue/30470465#30470465

Answer (score 0):

First `loadData()` function is not available in your code.

Second Use `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"` because of the following reasons.

For `button` when any javascript error comes page it will not do anything other than logging the error.

For `submit` it will submit the page whether any error occurs or not.

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="loadAjax()" />
```

Comment: I made these changes. When I click on Submit, nothing happens.

Comment: is your `loadAjax()` function calling ? if yes check once your browser console is there any javascript errors occurred.